# Joining date dimension multiple times? - Kimball's book on Data warehouse and Dimension Modeling

Tags: database, data-warehouse, dimension, dimensional-modeling, kimball

I'm reading Ralph Kimball's book on Data warehouse and Dimension Modeling and in chapter 6, there is this part about dimension role playing.

> Sometimes you discover other dates associated with each transaction,
> such as the requested ship date for the order. Each of the dates
> should be a foreign key in the fact table...
> **However, you cannot simply join these two foreign keys to the same date dimension table. SQL would interpret this two-way simultaneous
> join as requiring both the dates to be identical, which isn’t very
> likely.**

And I am not sure I understand the two last sentences. Does it mean you cannot join the date dimension multiple times if both dates in fact table have different value? Why?

Answer (score 3):

It’s not very well expressed but all that it is saying is that you need to alias the date dimension if you are going to join to it multiple times from different FKs in the Fact table.

This is true of any SQL statement where 2 tables are joined together more than once, it’s not specific to dimensional modelling.

Answer (score 3):

The (well) hidden message here is that you need *multiple* joins - *one for each dimension role*

Say you have a fact table with *entry date* `entry_d` and *booking date* `booking_d`

This would be **wrong** and is *probably* meant in the text

```
select * from fact
join time_dim tim
on fact.entry_d = tim.date_d and
   fact.book_d = tim.date_d;
```

And this is **right** using two independent joins to the time dimension

```
select * from fact
join time_dim entr on fact.entry_d = entr.date_d  
join time_dim book on fact.book_d = book.date_d;
```

Note also that if you use an *inner join* as in the example above you shoud make some elementary validaton and clenaing of both dates. The point is: you should recognise *fact rows* with invalid dates (not covered in time dimension or `NULL`) and handle them propertly - not *discard them silently* in the join.

For non trivial setups, especially when the fact table is *partitioned* on a time column, you choose the native `DATE` format and not some *surrogate key* as for other dimensions. (This is a *practical* rule - not covered in the *theory*)